# Optimize mysql query (SELECT)?

Tags: mysql

I have table with 300 000 records (MyISAM). I get record from this table with this function:

```
public function loadRows() {
    if (!$this->result)
        die("Nothing found!");
    $this->rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($this->result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        $this->rows[] = $r;
    //mysql_free_result($this->result);
    return $this->rows;
}
```

The estimate time for showing 100 records from this table  is 6 seconds, very slowly and the MEMORY used from this query is 512 MB. Where I'm wrong?

The query is:

```
SELECT i.* FROM inv i 
LEFT JOIN (inv_m im) ON (i.m_id = im.id)
LEFT JOIN (inv_f iff) ON (iff.num = i.num)
LEFT JOIN (temp_a ta) ON (ta.num = i.num)
WHERE i.vid = 1
AND iff.num IS NULL
AND ta.num IS NULL
LIMIT 100
```

For i.vid I show all records.

Declared INDEXES:

**i.m_id INDEX**

**im.id PRIMARY KEY**

**iff.num INDEX**

**i.num INDEX**

**ta.num INDeX**

THE EXPLAIN RESULT

```
id  select_type  table  type     possible_keys  key      key_len  ref                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       i      ref      vid            vid      4        const               85343   Using where
1   SIMPLE       im     eq_ref   PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        checksys_r1.i.m_id  1 
1   SIMPLE       iff    ref      num            num      182      checksys_r1.i.num   1       Using where
1   SIMPLE       ta     ref      num            num      194      checksys_r1.i.num   1       Using where
```

Comment: You're joining four tables, but talking about only one. Post more details about your schema.

Comment: Are the `num` fields indexed?

Comment: If you add an index to the `inv.num`, `inv_f.num` and `temp_a.num` columns, you should see a speed increase

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN results.

Comment: All of this columns are indexes

Comment: All the columns on which the join is done are varchar or number?

Comment: num is varchar(60), m_id is int(11)

Comment: That is the problem, index on a varchar is of no use..

Comment: @SashiKant, please explain your statement "index on a varchar is of no use".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with running:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT i.* FROM inv i 
LEFT JOIN (inv_m im) ON (i.m_id = im.id)
LEFT JOIN (inv_f iff) ON (iff.num = i.num)
LEFT JOIN (temp_a ta) ON (ta.num = i.num)
WHERE i.vid = 1
AND iff.num IS NULL
AND ta.num IS NULL
LIMIT 100
```

look for things like a full row scan, file i/o, etc.  Post the results here.  Sometimes a table might need repairing as well.

Also, is there any reason you're using MyISAM over InnoDB?

Comment: the tables inv, ivm_m are myIsam, but table temp_a is innoDB

Comment: If you take out the i.vid = 1 (for now), does the query run much faster?

Comment: Also I don't see i.vid as having an index.  Ideally any column you use in a WHERE, HAVING or JOIN clause should be indexed.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possible causes, both are probably contributing.
Firstly, try to avoid selecting * wherever possible. Explicitly specifying the columns is going to save you per join queries against the master database to lookup the column names over and over again.
The 2nd one is that you are specifying a where clause which will only run after your joins. So it's going to create a massive recordset with all your joins, and then filter that record set afterwards. Moving your condition onto the join itself should get you some more performance increases.
So.....

```
SELECT i.Column1, i.Column2, i.Column3 
FROM inv i 
LEFT JOIN (inv_m im) ON (i.m_id = im.id AND i.vid = 1)
LEFT JOIN (inv_f iff) ON (iff.num = i.num AND iff.num IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN (temp_a ta) ON (ta.num = i.num AND ta.num IS NULL)
LIMIT 100
```